# Permissions are not recognized

Tags: android, permissions, android-service

I have a problem with permissions in android. I want to track if my device sent or received a sms. For this, I use a service that runs in background.

Permissions in mainfest.xml:

```
<uses-permssion android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permssion android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Here is the errorlog:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider 
com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider from ProcessRecord{2c9f3ff 
1676:mypackagename.myappname/u0a54} (pid=1676, uid=10054) requires
android.permission.READ_SMS or android.permission.WRITE_SMS
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> requires android.permission.READ_SMS or android.permission.WRITE_SMS

You don't actually use those permissions, because of the typo. Instead of:

```
uses-permssion
```

you should have

```
uses-permission
```

Comment: Thanks! There are 10 permissions in my manifest...I didn't see this stupid mistake :(